# Netbeans 12.4 - Where is the option to create a Master/Detail Sample Form?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, master-detail

Past versions of Netbeans have the option to create a **Master/Detail Sample Form** but I can't find that in Netbeans 12.4:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it either. There is an old NetBeans Bug Report [NETBEANS-582 Missing menuitem "Swing GUI Forms > Master/Detailed Sample Form"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-582) which raised this issue for NetBeans 9, and it remains unresolved.

A comment for that bug suggested "*The fact that that specific sample is missing is somehow connected to the fact that it is the only sample found in the forms.j2ee module*", so I tried "*Activating Java Web and EE*" on NetBeans 12.4 but that didn't help.

Since the wizard for a **Master/Detail Sample Form** does exist in NetBeans 8.2, I suppose you could generate the form on 8.2, and then copy the generated code over to NetBeans 12.4, but that may not be as simple as it sounds, and even it works it is not a satisfactory approach.

Beyond that, all you can really do is to post a new comment for the existing bug stating that the issue still exists in NetBeans 12.4, and request a resolution.